# Lookup table by int in C using hash

Tags: c, algorithm, hash

I have simple string to int mapping. How should I do lookup by int using hash or other efficient algorithm (please provide some example)?

```
struct string_int_map {
    char *str;
    int val;
};


struct string_int_map s_to_i_map[] {
    { "test1",  45 },
    { "test2",  95 },
    { "test3",  83 },
    { "test4",  67 },
};
```

Sol:

Sort an array and then perform binary search. Thanks for the help people.

Comment: What's the purpose of this particular piece of code? It seems really backwards, as normally you write a simple high-speed hash function, of which there are multitudes in textbooks that vary in terms of difficulty of implementation and speed, then work that into a standard-issue hash table, normally an array of single-linked entries.

Comment: If the `struct` array is sorted by `val` a binary search on `val` would be quick.

Comment: For maximum speed, but at the cost of memory, use an array and let the hash value be the index. It does not get faster than that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Weather and klutt. Can you please give me simple example?

Comment: The [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is well known. We don't supply code examples here, sorry.

Comment: no prob. thanks for reference. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort an array and perform binary search. Thanks @Weather for giving the reference.